# Retrieve last element of a column from each group and use it as first element of the same column in next group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows

```
Domain     Baseline     PlanningPeriod     Actual   
-------------------------------------------------      
Dom 1       Jan 18        1/1/18            10
Dom 1       Jan 18        1/2/18            20
Dom 1       Jan 18        1/3/18            25
Dom 1       Jan 18        1/4/18            24
Dom 1       Feb 18        1/2/18            60
Dom 1       Feb 18        1/3/18            20
Dom 1       Feb 18        1/5/18            40
Dom 1       Feb 18        1/12/18           70
Dom 1       Mar 18        1/3/18            11
Dom 1       Mar 18        1/4/18            12
Dom 1       Mar 18        1/12/18           18
Dom 1       Apr 18        1/4/18            40
Dom 1       Apr 18        1/5/18            25
Dom 1       Apr 18        1/6/18            15
-------------------------------------------------
```

Please note, there are different domains too

So am trying to get an extra column comulativeactual grouped by domain, baseline,planningperiod.

For the purpose I did the below query

```
select domain,baseline,planningperiod, actual,sum(actual) over(partition 
by domain, baseline order by domain,baseline,planningperiod) as cumilativeactual
```

Fortuantely it worked as expected and gave the following result

```
Domain     Baseline     PlanningPeriod     Actual    CumActual 
----------------------------------------------------------------      
Dom 1       Jan 18        1/1/18            10        10
Dom 1       Jan 18        1/2/18            20        30
Dom 1       Jan 18        1/3/18            25        55
Dom 1       Jan 18        1/4/18            24        79
Dom 1       Feb 18        1/2/18            60        60
Dom 1       Feb 18        1/3/18            20        80
Dom 1       Feb 18        1/5/18            40        120
Dom 1       Feb 18        1/12/18           70        190
Dom 1       Mar 18        1/3/18            11        11
Dom 1       Mar 18        1/4/18            12        23
Dom 1       Mar 18        1/12/18           18        31
Dom 1       Apr 18        1/4/18            40        40
Dom 1       Apr 18        1/5/18            25        65
Dom 1       Apr 18        1/6/18            15        80
--------------------------------------------------------
```

But my requirement is little wild. I need the last element of each group as the first element of next group. But the other values in the group exactly as above. So I really got confused on how to achieve that. I dont prefer cursor since there are around 20k records.

Means above should work as following.

```
Domain     Baseline     PlanningPeriod     Actual    CumActual 
----------------------------------------------------------------      
Dom 1       Jan 18        1/1/18            10        10
Dom 1       Jan 18        1/2/18            20        30
Dom 1       Jan 18        1/3/18            25        55
Dom 1       Jan 18        1/4/18            24        79
Dom 1       Feb 18        1/2/18            60        **79**
Dom 1       Feb 18        1/3/18            20        80
Dom 1       Feb 18        1/5/18            40        120
Dom 1       Feb 18        1/12/18           70        190
Dom 1       Mar 18        1/3/18            11        **190**
Dom 1       Mar 18        1/4/18            12        23
Dom 1       Mar 18        1/12/18           18        31
Dom 1       Apr 18        1/4/18            40        **31**
Dom 1       Apr 18        1/5/18            25        65
Dom 1       Apr 18        1/6/18            15        80
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a CTE and `LAG()`as

```
with cte as
(
select domain,
       baseline,
       planningperiod, 
       actual,
       sum(actual) over(partition 
       by domain, baseline order by domain,baseline,planningperiod) as cumilativeactual
from t
)
select domain,
       baseline,
       planningperiod, 
       actual,
       case when actual = cumilativeactual then
            lag(cumilativeactual, 1, 0) over(order by domain,baseline,planningperiod)
            else
            cumilativeactual end as cumilativeactual
from cte
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=650ca710e22c2eeb4d5d2b2b49acc6c7)**

Comment: This is the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution... It worked great. I expect a tiny bug since we are checking actual=cumulativeactual. Rather than that I made a small change into it and posting it as an answer which could be helpful for few

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want a cumulative sum with some additional logic:

```
select domain, baseline, planningperiod, actual,
       (case when seqnum = 1
             then lag(periodtotal) over (partition by domain, baseline order by domain, baseline, planningperiod)
             else cumulativeactual
        end) as cum_actual
from (select domain, baseline, planningperiod, actual,
             sum(actual) over (partition by domain, baseline order by domain, baseline, planningperiod) as cumulativeactual,
             sum(actual) over (partition by domain, baseline) as periodtotal,
             row_number() over (partition by domain, baseline order by domain, baseline, planningperiod) a seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 2):

A few window functions can help you replace the original rolling sum with the previous one on the first for each group.

**Example Data** (same groups and values as your example):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Amounts') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Amounts

CREATE TABLE #Amounts (
    Code VARCHAR(10),
    Actual INT,
    Ordering INT IDENTITY)

INSERT INTO #Amounts (
    Code,
    Actual)
VALUES
    ('A', 10),
    ('A', 20),
    ('A', 25),
    ('A', 24),

    ('B', 60),
    ('B', 20),
    ('B', 40),
    ('B', 70),

    ('C', 11),
    ('C', 12),
    ('C', 18),

    ('D', 40),
    ('D', 25),
    ('D', 15)
```

**Query**:

```
;WITH WindowFunctions AS
(
    SELECT
        A.Code,
        A.Actual,
        DenseRank = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY A.Code),
        RowNumberByCodeDesc = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Code ORDER BY A.Ordering DESC),
        RowNumberByCodeAsc = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Code ORDER BY A.Ordering ASC),
        CumulativeGeneral = SUM(A.Actual) OVER (PARTITION BY A.Code ORDER BY A.Ordering ASC)
    FROM
        #Amounts AS A
)
SELECT
    G.Code,
    G.Actual,
    G.DenseRank,
    G.RowNumberByCodeAsc,
    G.RowNumberByCodeDesc,
    G.CumulativeGeneral,
    PreviousFinishingCumulativeGeneral = P.CumulativeGeneral,
    CorrectedCumulative = CASE 
        WHEN G.RowNumberByCodeAsc = 1 AND P.CumulativeGeneral IS NOT NULL THEN P.CumulativeGeneral
        ELSE G.CumulativeGeneral END
FROM
    WindowFunctions AS G
    LEFT JOIN WindowFunctions AS P ON
        G.DenseRank - 1 = P.DenseRank AND
        P.RowNumberByCodeDesc = 1
```

**Results**:

```
Code    Actual  DenseRank   RowNumberByCodeAsc  RowNumberByCodeDesc CumulativeGeneral   PreviousFinishingCumulativeGeneral  CorrectedCumulative
A       10      1           1                   4                   10                  NULL                                10
A       20      1           2                   3                   30                  NULL                                30
A       25      1           3                   2                   55                  NULL                                55
A       24      1           4                   1                   79                  NULL                                79
B       60      2           1                   4                   60                  79                                  79
B       20      2           2                   3                   80                  79                                  80
B       40      2           3                   2                   120                 79                                  120
B       70      2           4                   1                   190                 79                                  190
C       11      3           1                   3                   11                  190                                 190
C       12      3           2                   2                   23                  190                                 23
C       18      3           3                   1                   41                  190                                 41
D       40      4           1                   3                   40                  41                                  41
D       25      4           2                   2                   65                  41                                  65
D       15      4           3                   1                   80                  41                                  80
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess as the output is sorted by `cumilativeactual` you can just use a `case when first_value/min_value of group then (select max(CumActual) from prev_group (using row_number()-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Sami for the nice solution. But I am making a little tweak on it which could make it little more accurate I guess.

Here my query is

```
with cte as
(
select domain,
       baseline,
       planningperiod, 
       actual,
       sum(actual) over(partition 
       by domain, baseline order by domain,baseline,planningperiod) as cumilativeactual,DENSE_RANK() over(order by domain,baseline) as DRank 
from t
)
select domain,
       baseline,
       planningperiod, 
       actual,
       case when Drank> LAG(DRank,1,0) over(order by domain,baseline,planningperiod) then
            lag(cumilativeactual, 1, 0) over(order by domain,baseline,planningperiod)
            else
            cumilativeactual end as cumilativeactual
from cte
```